# http.get() on Google maps API not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, http-get

I'm working on an Ionic 1 project wherein I am using the Google maps Geocoding API. The URL entered is proper, but it doesn't enter the .success function, or the .error function.

The code is as follows:

```
.controller('AgAddCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
  console.log("Agent Add");
  console.log($state.params.user);
$scope.hotelReg = function() {
var address = $scope.hName + ',' + $scope.hLocality + ',' + $scope.hCity;
var latitude;
var longitude;
var user = $state.params.user;
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&address=" + address;
$http.get(url)
  .success(function(data) {
    latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);
  })
  .error( function(error) {
    console.log("error map");
  })

Backendless.Data.of("Hotels").save({
  name: $scope.hName,
  locality: $scope.hLocality,
  city: $scope.hCity,
  amenities: $scope.hAmenities,
  latitude: latitude,
  longitude: longitude,
  agent_email: user.email
}).then( function( savedObject ) {
      console.log("success");
    })
  .catch( function( error ) {
      console.log("error upload");
    });
  }
 })
```

The flow is, the url variable value is set, the http.get request is made and the .success and .error is skipped. The backendless call is made, and throws an error (because latitude and longitude are not set), and then it returns to the .success function of the http.get call, and print the lat and lng value in the console. I don't understand why the flow is so. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: What version of angularjs? Success is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Async Behavior, Update your code like this, Backendless will only execute when http call is completed:

```
$http.get(url)
  .success(function(data) {
    latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);
        Backendless.Data.of("Hotels").save({
          name: $scope.hName,
          locality: $scope.hLocality,
          city: $scope.hCity,
          amenities: $scope.hAmenities,
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude,
          agent_email: user.email
        }).then( function( savedObject ) {
              console.log("success");
            })
          .catch( function( error ) {
              console.log("error upload");
            });
          }
         });
  })
  .error( function(error) {
    console.log("error map");
  })
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @SauravSircar glad i could help :-)